# Calling methods from namespace - declaring identifiers

Tags: c++, variables, namespaces

I asked a question about this program before, but still have questions. I made a namespace in the stdfax.h file and am trying to call the functions from main.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    deductions::getData(mStatus, nOfChildren, salary, contribPension);
    deductions::taxAmount(mStatus, nOfChildren, salary, contribPension);
}
```

The namespace looks like this:

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

namespace deductions
{
    const double marriedDeduction = 7000.00;
    const double singleDeduction = 4000.00;
    const double personalExemption = 1500.00;

    void getData(char& mStatus, int& nOfChildren, double& salary,
                 double& contribPension)   
    {cout << "\n\n  Enter marital status:  m or M (married), s or S (single):  ";
    cin  >> mStatus;

    if(mStatus == 'm' || mStatus == 'M') 
    {
        cout << "  Number of children:" << setfill(' ') << setw(40) << ' ';
        cin  >> nOfChildren;
    }    // end IF

    cout << setfill(' ');
    cout << "  Enter gross Salary:" << setw(40) << ' ';
    cin  >> salary;
    cout << "  Percentage of salary contributed to Pension (0 to 6):" << setw(6) << ' ';
    cin >> contribPension;
    cout << endl;}    // end getData( 

    double taxAmount(char mStatus, int nOfChildren, double salary,
             double contribPension)    
    {...}
};
```

The error is undeclared identifiers in main. Again, I've tried fiddling with it and can't get it to work. Sorry if it's a stupid error; I'm working with someone else's code and I've been looking at it so long it doesn't make sense anymore.

Declaring the variables in main gives the error that they're already defined in stdfax.

Comment: Where are `mStatus, nOfChildren, salary, contribPension` declared?

Comment: When I declare those in the namespace, it gives an error saying that they've already been defined in stdfax. It gives the same error when I try declaring them in main, too.

Comment: I would remove the namespace from stdfax.h. That file is reserved for precompiled headers in VS. Put it in it's own header ("deductions.h") and include that in main. Clean and rebuild your project.

Comment: That worked. This was for an assignment, and the instructions said to put the namespace in stdfax.h... Since the program won't work at all like that, seems like it was kind of a catch-22. Thank you

Comment: You can put it stdafx.h if you have to, but you just need to remember to do a full clean/rebuild of your project whenever you modify it.

Answer (score 3):

You haven't declared the variables that you pass as parameters:

```
int main()
{
    deductions::getData(mStatus, nOfChildren, salary, contribPension);
    deductions::taxAmount(mStatus, nOfChildren, salary, contribPension);
}
```

You must declare them. For example:

```
int main()
{
    char mStatus;
    int nOfChildren;
    double salary, contribPension;
    deductions::getData(mStatus, nOfChildren, salary, contribPension);
    deductions::taxAmount(mStatus, nOfChildren, salary, contribPension);
}
```

Comment: You can't pass a literal by reference unless it's const.

Comment: Oh, yeah. Forgot about that. Considering the function name is `getData`, the references should probably be const though and not references at all. Hard to say without the definitions.

Comment: Since get data returns `void` I would assume it gets the data from the user somehow and assigns it to the input parameters.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense :) I'm not very used to functions with side effects. I've removed the suggestion to initialize the values since they're probably set in the function.

Answer (score 2):

Please declare identifiers used in your method...

```
deductions::getData(mStatus, nOfChildren, salary, contribPension);
```